# Percorrer botões e caixa de textos com o tab

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa tarde à todos, dentro de windows form eu coloquei várias caixas de texto e botões, mas qdo eu navego entre com o tab eles estão desordenados, sei que se eu fizer um a um ficará na ordem, mas já foi feito. Tem como alterar de uma forma mais simples ou terei que refazer tudo um à um? Se num form de login por exemplo: digito os dados de login e senha, depois têm dois botões ok e sair, digitando o tab ele vai para o sair e não para o ok. eu poderia refazê-los e fazendo na ordem, mas há uma forma mais fácil de corrigir depois de prontos?
Grato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe a opção *Tab Order* no *Visual Studio* que facilita a ordenação dos componentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar nessa opção o *Visual Studio* irá mostrar como está o seu *Tab Order*.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bastando você clicar em cada um dos componentes na ordem que você deseja ordenar seus componentes.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra opção é você ir nas propeidades do seu componente, na categoria *Behavior* e definir a propriedade *TabIndex*. Sendo zero para o primeiro componente da sua tabulação e ir incrementando de 1 em 1 para os demais componentes.

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Existe também a possibilidade de configurar a propriedade de todos os componentes no Form. A propriedade TabIndex.
VC pode config via painel ou código.

A propriedade encontra-se no painel de propriedade de todos os componentes.
Ou
Controle.TabIndex = 1;

Onde controle pode ser um TextBox, um Painel,um PictureBox, entre outros controles.